# How to get data on chart based on selected date (Filtering data Chart JS with datepicker)

Tags: javascript, datepicker, chart.js

I've tried to get all data from specific date using code like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Try Chart</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  $("#firstdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#lastdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#filter").click(function() {
    var from_date = $("#firstdatepicker").val();
    var to_date = $("#lastdatepicker").val();
    if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
      console.log(from_date, to_date);
      var endpoint = '/api/data';

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    data: {
      from_date: from_date,
      to_date: to_date
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data); //get all data
      //get data by fields
      var hum = [], time = [];
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        hum.push(data[i].moisture);
        time.push(data[i].timestamp);
     }
      console.log(hum);
      console.log(time);
    //plot the chart

      var ctx = document.getElementById("moistureChart").getContext('2d');
      var moistureChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: time,
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'kelembaban',
                  data: hum,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgb(68, 145, 252)'
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                  '#331698'
                  ],
                  borderCapStyle: 'round',
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
          },
          options: {
              reponsive: true,
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero:true,
                          stepSize:10
                      },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'kelembaban'
                    }
                  }],
                  xAxes: [{
                          display: true,
                          ticks: {
                            min: from_date,
                            max: to_date,
                          },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Tanggal'
                    }
                  }]
              }
          }
      });
    },
    error: function(error_data){
      console.log(error_data)
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Please Select Date");
}
  });    
});
</script>


</head>


<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--Breadcrumbs-->
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Charts</li>
    <li style="margin-left: 10px">
    data from <input type="text" id="firstdatepicker" name="firstdatepicker" value="2020-03-14">
    to <input type="text" id="lastdatepicker" name="lastdatepicker" value="2020-03-15">
    <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info">
  </li>
  </ol>
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <canvas id="moistureChart" width="722" height="400">
        </canvas>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<!--buat kalender-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css"></link>

</body>
</html>
```

the data comes from API that i've made using django rest framework and run locally (localhost). The data is look like this :

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-15T11:46:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 70,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-15T12:00:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 75,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-15T13:00:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 75,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-16T07:00:00+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 80,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-17T07:00:00+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 70,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-18T07:00:00+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 77,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.7713794",
    "gps_longitude": "110.3753111",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
}
]
```

when i select the date from 15 march until 16 march, the chart doesn't display data from 15 until 16 march, but display all the data that i have in API. Is there any error on my code? I think there is something missing from my code. Can you help me with the code? I want the chart just displaying data from the date that i picked on datepicker. I am sorry, I am a newbie programmer

Comment: btw. I dont recommend to use that timestamp format, you should use numeric format referenced to absolut time or your string format but referenced to absolut timezone i mean use "+00:00" instead "+07:00" because this can generare issues quering by this atteibute in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with timebased data you should use time ChartsJS this way you can set limits in XAxe.

```
xAxes: [
        {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            minUnit: "minute",
            unit: "minute",
            unitStepSize: 4,
            min: moment(from_date).toDate(),//Date object type
            max: moment(to_date).toDate()//Date object type
          },
          ...
        }
      ],
```

Note that using this mode you need to use your data as follow:

```
{
    x: date,//Date object type
    y: value // Number
}
```

Note that your limits in time Object should be Date object. I recommend to use the library momenjs to manipulate date data since it has many compatibility. For example, the timestamp of your data retreived from server is not compatible with the constructor Date in Safari. but you can do something like

```
moment(data.timestamp).toDate()
```